# How To change dynamically "title x axis" in highcharts ?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to change dynamically "title x axis" of my chart in highcharts..
I tried but doesn't work.
Maybe i'm doing a mistake in javascript.

This my code in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9wopLLL7/

In the page there is a form:

```
<form name="region" action="#" method="post">
<p align="center">  
    <select onchange="selectRegion(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" size="1">
        <option selected value="">Seleziona la Region</option>
        <option value="0">Region 1</option>
        <option value="1">Region 2</option>
        <option value="2">Region 3</option>
        <option value="3">Region 4</option>
        <option value="4">Region 5</option>
        <option value="5">Region 6</option>
        <option value="6">Region 7</option>
        <option value="7">Region 8</option>
        <option value="8">Region 9</option>
        <option value="9">Region 10</option>    
    </select>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </noscript>
</p>
```

this is the function:

```
 function selectRegion(numReg){ 
  var RegionChart= myRegions[numReg][0];    
  var scritta= "This is the Region"+RegionChart+".";

  return scritta;

  start();
 }
```

the code of chart is enclose in function start();

In this way, when the value of form is chosen, the function selectRegion(numReg); run the function start(); and so the chart it will show.

The problem is that, the title of x axis should change with the value of form chosen, but doesn't work...

Please, can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your jsfiddle? It doesn't display any charts period. Is that the issue, or just the titles need to be changed?

Comment: Your code has a lot of bugs.. I suggest to pass `scritta` as param in the `start()` method. Then you can use that variable when creating chart. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9wopLLL7/1/

Comment: Thanks Pawel ! Is a good idea ;)